# Cant import sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
import sqlite3
```

Getting below error

```
C:\Users\pnkas\OneDrive\Documents\python\lesson\milestone_2_database\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/pnkas/OneDrive/Documents/python/lesson/milestone_2_database/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pnkas/OneDrive/Documents/python/lesson/milestone_2_database/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "C:\Users\pnkas\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\Users\pnkas\anaconda3\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sqlite3 dll... you have to find your system version.Later add it to this specific folder C:\Users\YOURUSER\Anaconda3\DLLs. This is basically depending on where you have installed anaconda and may change from user to user so make sure you add it to the proper folder.